# Why does CiviMail stop sending after the first 1,000 messages?

Tags: civimail, cron-job, scheduling

We have about 30k recipients in our lists and every time we send a mailing (New Mailing - Submit Mailing - Schedule Jobs - Execute Process Mailing) it stops after 1000 messages. We usually have to refresh the page and continue until it completes. How can we work around this? Thanks for your kind help.

Answer (score 6):

Did you setup the cronjob?

http://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/Managing+Scheduled+Jobs

It's the usual behavior of civicrm to send 1000 mails per cronjob. After that it waits x Minutes and sends the next batch of mails at the next cron run.

Comment: Worth noting here that visiting the Scheduled Mailings page triggers a mailing job run - this I think is undocumented, and might also confuse people ("Why do mailings send when I *don't* have a cron job configured??")

Answer (score 3):

Check *"Mailer Batch Limit"* at **CiviMail Settings** /civicrm/admin/mail?reset=1.

There must be zero if you want to be sent all mails at once.

Comment: I'm not shure, if it is a good idea, to senk 30k mails at once... depends very hard on infrastructure and mailservers used!